# Geodesics on a perturbed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let us consider $M$, a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$, isometrically embedded in $R^m$. Let us consider a geodesic $\gamma$ on $M$. Now, let us "perturb" (in other words, change slightly the coordinates of each point of $M$ in the ambient space) $M$ to $M'$, and consider the "image" $\gamma'$ (of $\gamma$) in $M'$. It seems very intuitive to me that there is a geodesic $\beta$ in $M'$ very "near" $\gamma'$. However, this question is vague (I hope the idea is clear) and I am unsure as to how to formulate the notions of "nearness" so that this "statement" will allow a proof. Furthermore, it also seems intuitively true that if $\gamma$ is a periodic geodesic, we can arrange that $\beta$ is also periodic.

So, my questions are:

1) How are such "perturbation problems" usually formulated? More specifically, how can we formulate the appropriate notion of "nearness" in this particular problem?

2) How can we prove the statement that there exists a geodesic near the perturbed curve in the new manifold?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you know about variational calculus?

Comment: In Hirsch's *Differential Topology* text he defines the strong and weak topology on spaces of embeddings of one manifold in another.  In the compact case they're the same, and you can further mod out by the diffeomorphism group of the domain to study the space of submanifolds.  He gives rather explicit constructions of the neighbourhoods via the tubular neighbourhood theorem.  I'd start there.